# scala java.time.ZonedDateTime.now error with timezone

Tags: scala, databricks

I want to get the current date from HK timezone using the following code:

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "<timezonename>" ) )
```

However, there is an error in scala   :

```
command-3866759536814832:3: error: not found: value ZoneId  
java.time.ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
```

Anyone has the idea ?

Comment: Did you imported `ZoneId`?

Answer (score 1):

```
@ java.time.ZonedDateTime.now( java.time.ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
res1: ZonedDateTime = 2020-06-30T18:50:23.117+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
```

works. You have to either import `ZoneId` as @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez noticed, or use full name.

Comment: how can I only get the date YYYY-MM-DD
java.time.ZonedDateTime.now( java.time.ZoneId.of( "Hongkong" ) ).toString()
output String = 2020-07-01T15:55:02.356+08:00[Hongkong]

Answer (score 0):

**Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez  already mentioned the problem.**

But you can use this way too:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Date, TimeZone}

val tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka")

val df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm Z")
df.setTimeZone(tz)
println(df.format(new Date()))
```